# lstlisting indent doubled

Tags: listings, code

I'm trying to use the listings packege. When I incert the following content which copied from the https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/code_listing

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}[language=Python]
    import numpy as np
        
    def incmatrix(genl1,genl2):
        m = len(genl1)
        n = len(genl2)
        M = None #to become the incidence matrix
        VT = np.zeros((n*m,1), int)  #dummy variable
        
        #compute the bitwise xor matrix
        M1 = bitxormatrix(genl1)
        M2 = np.triu(bitxormatrix(genl2),1) 
    
        for i in range(m-1):
            for j in range(i+1, m):
                [r,c] = np.where(M2 == M1[i,j])
                for k in range(len(r)):
                    VT[(i)*n + r[k]] = 1;
                    VT[(i)*n + c[k]] = 1;
                    VT[(j)*n + r[k]] = 1;
                    VT[(j)*n + c[k]] = 1;
                    
                    if M is None:
                        M = np.copy(VT)
                    else:
                        M = np.concatenate((M, VT), 1)
                    
                    VT = np.zeros((n*m,1), int)
        
        return M
    \end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

What I was intended to get was:
[image: Normal output]

However, I got this instead:
[image: Problem output]

Why is all my indent doubled? And how to deal with the long space in the left part of the paper?

I'm using VSCode with LaTeX Workshop as an editor, after I saved the code, it is automatically formatted. Is there where the problem formed?

Comment: Try removing the indentation for the whole `\begin{lstlistings}` block, and have it all indented "one less". After doing this on my computer it gets rid of the double indenting problem.

Answer (score 1):

I cleared all the code and the output files and copied the exact code from the question I posted. The problem dissappeared.

It seemed that it was the Tab I used that caused the problem. When I copied the code from this page, the Tab automatically turned into 4 spaces.

Comment: You can use, for example `\lstset{tabsize=4}` to set the tab size. By default `tabsize=8` is used, which is what you get in question.